# Widgets are not shown on editor with AppTheme

Tags: android, widget, styles, themes

So whenever I'm using the AppTheme as the Theme for my app, it works perfectly fine on the emulator and devices but on the editor I can not see all my widgets and layouts and all that stuff. If I switch the theme on the editor to Material light, the widgets are shown. But I do not want to see it as a Material light theme because I'm currently using my own theme which has AppTheme as it's parent. Is there any fix?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you mention the AppTheme code from styles.xml.
Have you changed colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent values from color.xml?

Comment: I added it and no I did not change the color values.